# NSIS - printing to prompt during command line install

Tags: nsis, command-line-arguments

I'm making installers for windows using NSIS and have a number of custom install options that the user can specify using the command line, for example:

```
installer.exe /IDPATH=c:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe InDesign CS5 /S
```

What I want to do is show these options to the person installing. I can easily enough parse the /? or /help parameters with ${GetParameters} and ${GetOptions}, but how do I do the actual printing to the command prompt?

Answer (score 10):

NSIS is a GUI program and does not really have the ability to write to stdout.

On XP and later you can do this with the system plugin:

```
System::Call 'kernel32::GetStdHandle(i -11)i.r0' 
System::Call 'kernel32::AttachConsole(i -1)' 
FileWrite $0 "hello"
```

On < XP, there is no AttachConsole and you need to call AllocConsole on those systems (Will probably open a new console window)

**Edit:**
You could open a new console if the parent process does not have one already with

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
System::Call 'kernel32::GetStdHandle(i -11)i.r0' 
System::Call 'kernel32::AttachConsole(i -1)i.r1' 
${If} $0 = 0
${OrIf} $1 = 0
 System::Call 'kernel32::AllocConsole()'
 System::Call 'kernel32::GetStdHandle(i -11)i.r0' 
${EndIf}
FileWrite $0 "hello$\n"
```

But it does not really make any sense as far as /? handling goes, you might as well open a message box when there is no console

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
StrCpy $9 "USAGE: Hello world!!" ;the message
System::Call 'kernel32::GetStdHandle(i -11)i.r0' ;try to get stdout
System::Call 'kernel32::AttachConsole(i -1)i.r1' ;attach to parent console
${If} $0 <> 0
${AndIf} $1 <> 0
 FileWrite $0 "$9$\n" 
${Else}
 MessageBox mb_iconinformation $9
${EndIf}
```

Comment: It would appear that simply pasting this code into the .oninit does nothing visible on an XP machine. Do I need to set anything up such as the values of i and r0? I also dont quite understand what each of these lines do. I would presume that the first line gets the handle of the current console, the second line links $0 to that console so that subsequent writes to that virtual file will end up in the console. Is this accurate? I also tried the longer code samples found on winamp forums when googling for nsis kernel32::attachconsole, but they seem to have the same problem.

Comment: After even more googling to random pages I think I've figured out that all the 'i' simply denotes that the following is an integer. As you can tell my knowledge of the windows api is very basic.

Comment: You need to run the program from within a open console (cmd.exe)

Comment: That is what I am doing. Using AllocConsole instead of AttachConsole seems to do nothing either.

Comment: Worked for me.  Except that it doesn't close.  I am guessing there is a fileClose type function to go with FileWrite

Comment: @Jon: There is a FreeConsole function if you want to force a disconnect from the console...

Answer (score 1):

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
StrCpy $9 "USAGE: Hello world!!" ;the message
System::Call 'kernel32::AttachConsole(i -1)i.r0' ;attach to parent console
${If} $0 != 0
 System::Call 'kernel32::GetStdHandle(i -11)i.r0' ;console attached -- get stdout
 FileWrite $0 "$9$\n" 
${Else}
 ;no console to attach -- show gui message
 MessageBox mb_iconinformation $9
${EndIf}
```

First attach console then get std handle. Before attach handles may (often will) be invalid.