# NSIS - printing to prompt during command line uninstall

Tags: command-line-arguments, nsis, uninstallation

I've written an installer for windows using NSIS.
If the program is run from a console i want to write some information to this console.

My code looks like the one in this question...

[NSIS - printing to prompt during command line install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103226/nsis-printing-to-prompt-during-command-line-install)

```
System::Call 'kernel32::GetStdHandle(i -11)i.r0' 
System::Call 'kernel32::AttachConsole(i -1)i.r1' 
FileWrite $0 "hello"
```

There is no problem with the installer. But if i run the uninstaller there is no output and $1 == 0.

Is there a difference between installer and uninstaller for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uninstaller will run a copy of itself from %Temp% unless you start it with the special `_?=$Instdir` parameter. (It does this so `Delete "$Instdir\uninstall.exe"` works)

This means that `AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)` in the second uninstaller instance will try to attach to a parent process that does not have a console. The parent has no console because a NSIS uninstaller is a GUI application and those don't get a console automatically and the `_?=` handling happens before .onInit so the **hack** to attach to one never happens.

I don't think there is a way to work around this without using `_?=`. Using AttachConsole is a hack and will never work perfectly in a GUI application...